# Remove padding from table

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to insert comments in the right side of the table

I did `aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index` but when I have many comments the table starts to have a lot of padding/margin in the left side.

What I wanted is to have the normal table with the 3 rows on the left and in the right have the exact same size for the comments and scroll like this

[Please click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qp46I.png)

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Status</b></td>
      <td class="ng-binding">xpto</td>


      <td rowspan="6" class="tdForCommentHistory col-xs-4" id="ticketCol" style="">
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="commentHeaderPanelGroup">

          <!-- ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse0">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:04, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse1">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:06, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse2">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:07, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse3">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:11, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse4">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasfafsasf</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asffas</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 16:54:22, 16-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse5">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asffsafas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">safasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:31:52, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse6">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgddd</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:37, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse7">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgddd</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:37, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse8">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:49, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse9">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:49, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse10">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:55, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse11">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:55, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse12">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasasfsa</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse12" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asfasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:33:57, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse13">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasasfsa</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse13" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asfasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:33:57, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Aktuelle Mobilfunknummer</b></td>
      <td class="ng-binding">+49 15254722323</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Neue Mobilfunknummer</b><i class="required-asterix">*</i></td>
      <td class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" style="
    text-align:  left;
"><span style="
    text-align:  left;
"><b style="
    text-align:  left;
">+49</b></span></span>
          <input name="newMobileNumber" validator="/^(\d{11})$/" maxlength="11" id="newMobileNumber" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="fehlerhafte Mobilfunknummer-Eingabe" ng-model="vm.MobileChangeData.NewMobileNumber" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-vm.-mobile-change-data.-new-mobile-number ng-touched"
            placeholder="Neue Mobilfunknummer" required="" style="">
        </div>
      </td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This resolve your problem? #commentHeaderPanelGroup{ overflow: auto; max-height: 200px;}

Answer (score 0):

```css
#ticketCol {
  position: relative;
}

#commentHeaderPanelGroup {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Status</b></td>
      <td class="ng-binding">xpto</td>


      <td rowspan="6" class="tdForCommentHistory col-xs-4" id="ticketCol" style="">
        <div style="overflow-y: scroll;" id="commentHeaderPanelGroup">

          <!-- ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse0">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse0" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:04, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse1">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:06, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse2">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:07, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse3">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">fasfsas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">afsafsasf</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 13:40:11, 11-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse4">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasfafsasf</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse4" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asffas</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 16:54:22, 16-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse5">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asffsafas</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse5" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">safasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:31:52, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse6">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse6" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgddd</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:37, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse7">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse7" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgddd</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:37, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse8">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse8" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:49, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse9">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse9" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:49, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse10">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse10" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:55, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse11">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">dddd</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse11" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">ghhgdddhhhh</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:32:55, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse12">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasasfsa</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse12" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asfasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:33:57, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
          <div class="panel-group ng-scope" ng-repeat="aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="commentHeaderPanel">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                  <a data-toggle="collapse" id="commentHeader" href="#collapse13">
                    <b class="ipp-color ng-binding">asfasasfsa</b>
                  </a>
                </h4>
              </div>
              <div id="collapse13" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <p class="ng-binding">asfasffsa</p>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-footer">
                  <div class="text-right ng-binding">
                    <b class="ng-binding">motu</b> - 11:33:57, 17-10-2018
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- end ngRepeat: aTicket in vm.ticketHistory track by $index -->
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Aktuelle Mobilfunknummer</b></td>
      <td class="ng-binding">+49 15254722323</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><b>Neue Mobilfunknummer</b><i class="required-asterix">*</i></td>
      <td class="form-group">
        <div class="col-xs-7 input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon" style="
    text-align:  left;
"><span style="
    text-align:  left;
"><b style="
    text-align:  left;
">+49</b></span></span>
          <input name="newMobileNumber" validator="/^(\d{11})$/" maxlength="11" id="newMobileNumber" validator-invoke="watch" validator-error="fehlerhafte Mobilfunknummer-Eingabe" ng-model="vm.MobileChangeData.NewMobileNumber" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid-maxlength ng-valid ng-valid-required ng-valid-vm.-mobile-change-data.-new-mobile-number ng-touched"
            placeholder="Neue Mobilfunknummer" required="" style="">
        </div>
      </td>


    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```